# 301 or 302 redirect affecation in SEO

Tags: apache, redirect, seo, url-rewriting

I have a page A, and I have done a redirection from B to A. But I have a doubt, I want google to index B instead of A. What do I need a 301 or a 302 redirection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use 302 to keep redirected URL in the SERP

By using a 302 redirect, both URLs will stay in Google index and might be displayed in Search Engines Result Pages (SERP).

NB: You can not replace one by the other and remove destination URL from the SERP.

### Why ? because Search Engines use standard

#### 301 means the document has moved

So for Google, if `B` redirects with a 301 to `A`, `B` will totally disappear from the index and all information associated to `B` will be asociated to `A`.

#### 302 means the document is temporary somewhere else

It means that the first URL `B` is still valid. In this case Google will keep `B` in its index and all informations associated with it (backlinks, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! It was really useful for me :)